# Compiling android project with a library project fails with missing classes.jar

Tags: java, android, ant, library-project

I'm making an app that depends on the Android v7 appCompat support library. When I'm  trying to build the project with Ant, I get an error from dex stating that it can't find the file classes.jar from the appCompat project's bin directory. Here's what I have done:

1. I copied the appCompat directory under the SDK over to my project. It is now one of the top-level directories along with libs, res, src etc.
2. I added the library to my project:

   ```
   android update project --target 1 --path . --library .\appCompat
   ```

   (--target 1 refers to api level 22 on my system.)
3. I generated build files for the appCompat project:

   ```
   cd appCompat
   android update lib-project --target 1 --path .
   ```
4. I went back to my project and attempted building it:

   ```
   cd ..
   ant clean debug
   ```

   Everything goes smoothly until I get the following:

   ```
   -dex:
         [dex] input: C:\Users\Tuukka\Documents\app\bin\classes
         [dex] input: C:\Users\Tuukka\Documents\app\appcompat\bin\classes.jar
         [dex] input: C:\Users\Tuukka\Documents\app\appcompat\libs\android-support-v4.jar
         [dex] input: C:\Users\Tuukka\Documents\app\appcompat\libs\android-support-v7-appcompat.jar
         [dex] Pre-Dexing C:\Users\Tuukka\Documents\app\appcompat\libs\android-support-v4.jar -> android-support-v4-7d4b9d18b52617b1310b8c2397abe6b7.jar
         [dex] Pre-Dexing C:\Users\Tuukka\Documents\app\appcompat\libs\android-support-v7-appcompat.jar -> android-support-v7-appcompat-af2360631cde3dc57c1fde6f23204ddb.jar
         [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into C:\Users\Tuukka\Documents\app\bin\classes.dex...
          [dx]
          [dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
          [dx] java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Tuukka\Documents\app\appcompat\bin\classes.jar (No such file or directory)
   ```

There is indeed no classes.jar in appCompat\bin. In fact, after looking through the entire build output, it seems such a thing was never built, yet Ant seems to expect that it exists.

Is there something I'm missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem is caused by the project not being set up as a library project. If you are setting up everything by hand you can fix this by adding `android.library=true` to the `[your project]/appCompat/project.properties` file.