# Ant, Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

Tags: android, ant

Let's create a clean new project:

```
$ mkdir ApiTest
$ android create project --target android-22 --name ApiTest \
 --path ./ApiTest --activity MyActivity --package com.example.apitest
```

Only add `RecyclerView` to layout so `res/layout/main.xml` looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Copy support libraries from `${ANDROID_SDK_PATH}/extras/android/support/v7/`:

```
$ ls ApiTest/libs/
android-support-v4.jar            android-support-v7-cardview.jar
android-support-v7-appcompat.jar  android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar
```

Build & install:

```
$ ant debug
$ adb install -r bin/ApiTest-debug.apk
```

And when I open the Activity exception is raised:

```
09-28 20:02:02.346: E/AndroidRuntime(28688): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-28 20:02:02.346: E/AndroidRuntime(28688): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.apitest/com.example.apitest.MyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
09-28 20:02:02.346: E/AndroidRuntime(28688):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2357)
09-28 20:02:02.346: E/AndroidRuntime(28688):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2419)
...
```

What is wrong here?

I compile on 64bit Fedora 21 using openjdk java compiler:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_60"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I overlooked that there are two types of Android Support Libraries. Libraries without resources (e.g. *android-support-v4*) and libraries with resources (e.g. *appcompat* and *recyclerview*). See [Adding Support Libraries](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library).

To add recyclerview library (with resources) using command line and *ant* build tool first copy whole recyclerview directory from *Android SDK* directory to your project directory and update ant build files

```
$ cd ${ANDROID_PROJECT_DIR}
$ cp -r ${ANDROID_SDK_DIR}/extras/android/support/v7/recyclerview/ .
$ android update lib-project --path recyclerview --target android-22
$ android update project --path . -l recyclerview
```

The third command should add line `android.library=true` to `recyclerview/project.properties` which in my case didn't so I added it manually. When I tried it with *appcompat* library it work as expected.

Another thing is that in the `recyclerview/src` directory was missing. So simply create

```
$ mkdir recyclerview/src
```

And that is it. Now it compiles and runs.

```
$ ant clean && ant debug && adb install -r bin/ApiTest-debug.apk
```

These links helped me:

- [How to add Android libraries with resources without using Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525408/how-to-add-android-libraries-with-resources-without-using-eclipse)
- [Compiling android project with a library project fails with missing classes.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766740/compiling-android-project-with-a-library-project-fails-with-missing-classes-jar)

Comment: Fixed my issue with your guide. thanks! I have tried many ways: update support library, and copy library from extras to project libs dir. None works. The solution is copy recyclerview to project and create dependency, and copy only android-support-v4.jar to libs/